# C# How to Access Asp.net Label value from array type Webmethode?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to call array type method from jquery so I have written the below code. I also wrote a Web Method. I want to know how to pass ASP.NET label control's value to 'GetMessages' method's parameter?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {           
            $("#tblCustomers tbody tr").remove();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "GetDataByJquery.aspx/GetMessages",
                data: '{roomId: "' + $("#lblRoomId").val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        var rows = "<tr>"
                    + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Username + "</td>"
                    + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Sex + "</td>"
                    + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.Text + "</td>"
                    + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.TimeStamp + "</td>"
                    + "<td class='customertd'>" + item.UserID + "</td>"
                    + "</tr>";
                        $('#tblCustomers tbody').append(rows);
                    }))
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        });    
    </script>
```

Here is the Web Method. I am unable to get the label control value to pass to the below Webmethod.

```
[WebMethod]
        public static Messages[] GetMessages(string roomId)
        {
            List<Messages> messages = new List<Messages>();           
            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LinqChatConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    string query = "[Get_Messages]";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomId", roomId);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Messages message = new Messages();
                        message.Username = reader.GetString(0);
                        message.Sex = reader.GetString(1);
                        message.Text = reader.GetString(2);
                        message.TimeStamp = reader.GetString(3);
                        message.UserID = reader.GetString(4);
                        messages.Add(message);
                    }
                }
            }
            return messages.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: What is not working? and why you said below code is working fine?

Comment: data: '{roomId: "' + $("#lblRoomId").val() + '" }'

Comment: what are you getting as parameter value when you debug 'roomId'

Comment: what is the lable controller

Comment: @sajanyamaha i am getting 'undefined' in parameter.

Comment: is the label dynamically created,and is the id correct,paste tour html as well

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblRoomId" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="5"></asp:Label>

Comment: not dynamically..its created from design side..

Comment: @GovindKhandare check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is you JQuery is not able to find your label with that ID so returning undefined,

When you use runat="server" the rendered id may not be 'lblRoomId'.

So after rendering check your label Id and use that in

```
 data: '{roomId: "' + $('#<%=lblRoomId.ClientID%>').text();  + '" }',
```

and change `.Val()` to `.text()`

and also remove `visible="false"` instead `style="display:none;"`

Comment: please paste here your label id from 'view page source'

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblRoomId" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="5"></asp:Label>

Answer (score 0):

Use $("[id$='lblRoomId']").val() instead of $("#lblRoomId").val().

Comment: it is also not working..when i debugging and pointing on parameter there showing 'Undefined'.

Comment: try this one 
var g = $('#<%=lblRoomId.ClientID%>').text();

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Tom, element with `Visible = "false"` will not be available on `DOM`. Remove that and hide it through `style="display:none"`

`.val()` gets value from input controls but label is not input control. You should replave `.val()` to `.html()` and it will work.

If your label is `asp:Label` (server side control) then use

```
$("[id$=lblRoomId]").html()
```

Comment: it is also not working..when i debugging and pointing on parameter there showing 'Undefined'. –

Comment: not in any markups..its in form..  <form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="btnSend" defaultfocus="txtMessage">   <asp:Label ID="lblRoomId" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="5"></asp:Label>   </form>

Comment: Just to add another hint: With the parameter Visible="false" it will not render the label. So the label does not exist in the html markup

Comment: @ Tom ..you correct..it is the issue.. so how to get that visible false control value? because I dnt want to show that control value.

Comment: @GovindKhandare If you read answer properly then you will get it, and as Tom mentioned, it was just another hint, even after removing Visible=false, your code will not work. You have to do all changes I suggested